# WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Estoy intentando mostrar una lista de ofertas registradas en una base de datos mediante JSF a través de un flujo. No obstante, cuando quiero probar si funciona o no aparece esta excepción:

```
WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped

FATAL:   JSF1073: se ha interceptado org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException durante el procesamiento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
FATAL:   WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:708)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:761)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getCurrentSelectedValues(MenuRenderer.java:648)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.java:122)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

Cuento con el siguiente código:

**Inscripción.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"

  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">



      <body>

          <ui:composition template="./../WEB-INF/Template2.xhtml">

              <ui:define name="content">
                  <h2>Seleccione una oferta</h2>
                  <h:form>
                      <h:selectOneRadio value="#{inscripcion.ofertaId}"
                                        layout="pageDirection"
                                        required="true">
                          <f:selectItems value="##{ofertasFacadeREST.findAll()}"
                                         var="o"
                                         itemValue="#{o.id}"
                                         itemLabel="#{o.nombre}"></f:selectItems>
                      </h:selectOneRadio>
                      <p:commandButton id="aceptar" value="Aceptar" action="confirmar"/>

                  </h:form>
              </ui:define>

          </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

**inscripcion-flow**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
<flow-definition id="inscripcion">
<flow-return id="goHome">
<from-outcome>/index</from-outcome>
</flow-return>
</flow-definition>
</faces-config>
```

---

**inscripcion.java**

```
package com.mycompany.pfinalpsegrupo2.inscripcion;




import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


     @Named
 @FlowScoped("inscripcion")
public class inscripcion implements Serializable{

int ofertaId;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public int getOfertaId() {
        return ofertaId;
    }

    public void setOfertaId(int ofertaId) {
        this.ofertaId = ofertaId;
    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }


     }
```

---

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Cómo inicias el flujo?

Comment: ...Lo que he dejado escrito en la pregunta es todo lo que he utilizado, no tengo nada más

Comment: Para iniciar el flujo, se hace mediante una navegación al flujo; p.ej `<p:commandButton value="Èmpezar" outcome="inscripcion"/>` ¿No tienes nada de eso? ¿Vas directamente a `inscripcion.xhtml`?

Comment: Lo tengo así en la pantalla de inicio, a modo de menuitem:<p:menuitem value="Inscribirse" url="/faces/inscripcion/inscripcion.xhtml"/>

Answer (score 0):

El flujo no se inicializa llamando a la primera página de éste, es al revés. Accedes al flujo y, una vez inicializado, se llama automáticamente a la primera página (que se llama igual que el flujo).

Al llamar a la página directamente, no entras en el contexto del flujo y por lo tanto falla al inyectar/crear el bean.

Lo que tienes que hacer es empezar el flujo mediante navegación, por ejemplo un `outcome` al flujo (al flujo, no a la primera página).

En tu caso:

```
<p:menuitem value="Inscribirse" url="/faces/inscripcion/inscripcion.xhtml"/>
```

simplemente va a una URL; no hay lógica de creación del contexto. Cámbialo a

```
<p:menuitem value="Inscribirse" outcome="inscripcion"/>
```

para que use la navegación JSF.

Comment: Funcionó. Muchas gracias